# get the value from 2-d arraylist in session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arraylist

I have an 2-d arraylist with 2 fixed columns and dynamic rows. The arraylist will be assigned to the session variable at the end of the code below. My question is how can loop thorugh the arraylist from the session to get its value?

```
If .SQLDS.Tables(.sSQLDSTbl).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim NoOfAdjType(1, .SQLDS.Tables(.sSQLDSTbl).Rows.Count - 1)

    For iRow As Integer = 0 To .SQLDS.Tables(.sSQLDSTbl).Rows.Count - 1
        If Not .SQLDS.Tables(.sSQLDSTbl).Rows(iRow).Item("i_commAmt") Is System.DBNull.Value Then
            NoOfAdjType(0, iRow) = .SQLDS.Tables(.sSQLDSTbl).Rows(iRow).Item("productType")
            NoOfAdjType(1, iRow) = Format(.SQLDS.Tables(.sSQLDSTbl).Rows(iRow).Item("i_commAmt"), "#,##0.00")
        End If
    Next

        Session("iNoOfAdjAmtType") = NoOfAdjType
End If
```

I have tried this but it's giving me error **'Too many arguments to 'Public Overridable Default Property Item(index As Integer) As Object'**

```
Dim NoOfAdjType As ArrayList = CType(Session("iNoOfAdjAmtType"), ArrayList)
For i As Integer = 0 To NoOfAdjType.Count
    Dim a As String = NoOfAdjType(0, i)
    Dim b As String = NoOfAdjType(1, i)
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type you are dealing with is `Object(,)`. So when reading from the session you can cast it back to this type.

Here's an [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5.aspx) which illustrates how to read values from session:

```
Dim NoOfAdjType as Object(,) = CType(Session("iNoOfAdjAmtType"), Object(,))
' do something with the list
```

And if you wanted to perform the check safely ensuring that there is an item with the given id in the session:

```
If Session.Item("iNoOfAdjAmtType") IsNot Nothing Then
    ' We have a value in the session with the given id
    Dim NoOfAdjType as Object(,) = CType(Session("iNoOfAdjAmtType"), Object(,))
End If
```

Comment: thanks but how can i get the number of rows in the arraylist?

Comment: @Danferd, `NoOfAdjType.GetLength(0)` and `NoOfAdjType.GetLength(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain what is the data-type of array, but this how you manipulate the multi-dimension arrays in VB.NET assuming data-type as object

```
' declaring variable of multi-dim array
Dim NoOfAdjType As Object(,)
' create array object of needed dimension (you may use redim keyword)
NoOfAdjType = new Object(1, .SQLDS.Tables(.sSQLDSTbl).Rows.Count - 1) {}

...

' push it in session
 Session("iNoOfAdjAmtType") = NoOfAdjType

...

' get back from session
NoOfAdjType = DirectCast(Session("iNoOfAdjAmtType"), Object(,))
...
For i As Integer = 0 To NoOfAdjType.GetLength(0)
   For j As Integer = 0 To NoOfAdjType.GetLength(1)
      Dim a As Object = NoOfAdjType(i, j);
      ...
   Next
Next
```

See this MSDN article for array in VB.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Dim a As String = NoOfAdjType(0)(0,0)
```

Or use

```
For Each arr As Object(,) In NoOfAdjType

Next
```